# Highlight different link after some seconds

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I need to create [this](http://solid-am.com) homepage and as you can see [here](http://5.79.100.200/~callum/solid/) the only thing that is missing is the highlight of the name on the left as time passes.

It is a Wordpress site so I believe I have to do it with php.

As can be seen in any artists' page (for example [here](http://5.79.100.200/~callum/solid/binh/)) I have been able to highlight the individual artist on each page.

But how can I do it to loop all the time in the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

From what can be observed from the 2 Links you posted here, the issue may most probably stem from the fact that you have not tied the Slider to the Menus on the left. On the Site: http://solid-am.com/, a relationship exist between each menu on the left and the Slider Image. The relationship is based on the **"css class-name" of the list-item that wraps the menu link on the left** and the **"data-id" Attribute of the list element wrapping the slider-image**.

For example, on that page; the CSS Class for the Menu ***List Item*** on the Left for the Artist **"BIHN"** is **artist-233**. Intentionally, by design as well, the ***List Element*** wrapping the Image of **"BIHN"** has the data-id attribute: **data-id="233"**.

Now, this simply says that you have to design and arrange your implementation to take those into consideration. And by the way; you can as well implement those on your own using javascript to add the classes, but that would be a lot of work and much waste of time (especially since this is a plugin).

It was also observed that you are using a different Plugin as the Site above. The Site http://solid-am.com/ uses BX Slider. And if you want to make things easier for your self, you may try that Slider since it may do the heavy liftings for you. Here is the [Link to the BX Slider Plugin download Page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bxslider-wp/). Here is the [Link to the  Documentation Page](http://bxslider.com/options) for the BX Slider.

It is hoped this little Info helps you rethink your Strategy....

Good Luck & Cheers!!!

Comment: I have seen the relations between the slider and the links in the other site but I thought that maybe I could do it individually.What I mean is that, I set the slider to rotate every 2 seconds and write some code to do the same about the links. Highlight next every 2 seconds. So I would get the same result. You recommend re-doing it using the same slider?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var artistProfile = document.getElementsByTagName("dd");
artistProfile.style.color = "white";
</script>
```